# Can't change legend title of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Can't change this legend title!

I have been trying to change the legend title, but nothing has worked. I've gone through these forums and every thing people have suggested has not worked (guides, manipulating things like scale_color_continuous, etc.).

The other issue is that the "size" function in the geom_point aes command shows in the legend (i.e., it gives a shape to the size command under the shapes for my actual data).

I've been trying for hours to fix these issues, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the reproducible code to produce the chart:

```
## Create data frame
Predictor <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
TimePoint <- c("Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post")
value <- c(33, 32, 31, 40)
SE <- c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
dataframe <- data.frame(Predictor, TimePoint, estimate, SE)

## Define factors and reorder levels of TimePoint
dataframe$TimePoint <- as.factor(dataframe$TimePoint)
dataframe$Predictor <- as.factor(dataframe$Predictor)
dataframe$TimePoint = factor(dataframe$TimePoint, levels = c("Pre", "Post"), ordered = TRUE)

## Create Plot
ggp <- ggplot(data=dataframe, aes(x=TimePoint, y=value, group=Predictor)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE), width=.1) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Predictor, size=2)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 50)) + ## specifies upper and lower of y
  ylab("Value") +
  xlab("
       Timing")+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0.25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, 5), limits = c(0, 50), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = .6, colour = "black", linetype=1),         
        axis.text = element_text( angle = 0, color="black", size=18, face=2),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=18, face=2),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=18, face=2, margin=margin(r=20)))

print(ggp)
```

I have tried every recommendation I have found on here. Things like the following:

```
ggp + scale_color_discrete(name = "New Legend Title")

ggp + labs(color = "New Legend Title")

ggp + scale_fill_discrete(name="New Legend Title")

ggp + guides(col = guide_color(title = "New Legend Title"))

ggp + labs(color = "New Legend Title")
```

Comment: On my machine `+ labs(shape = "Unknown") + guides(size = "none")` works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Size problem:**

Arguments passed to `aes()` are mappings of your data to the aesthetic elements of the graph. When the aesthetic isn't supposed to be mapped with your data, it is just a constant argument (i.e. `size = 2` versus `shape = Predictor`), you want to pass the argument outside `aes()`:

```
geom_point(aes(shape=Predictor), size=2)
```

**Legend name problem:**

Also, each aesthetic (color, fill, size, alpha, etc.) has it's own legend, and you have to specify which one you're wanting to change. In the examples you gave at the end, you were manipulating the *color* aes., but you want to manipulate the *shape* aes.:

- `ggp + scale_shape_discrete(name = "New Legend Title")`
- `ggp + labs(shape = "New Legend Title")`
- `ggp + guides(col = guide_shape(title = "New Legend Title"))`

**Extra:**

The `size` argument for width of a line is deprecated, use `linewidth` instead:

```
theme(axis.line = element_line(linewidth = .6, colour = "black", linetype=1))
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Still new to r coding, so I appreciate the help and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

remove the `size` from `aes()` and keep it outside `aes()` in `geom_point`
use `shape` in `guides`

```r
ggp <- ggplot(data=dataframe, aes(x=TimePoint, y=value, group=Predictor)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-SE, ymax=value+SE), width=.1) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Predictor), size=4) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 50)) + ## specifies upper and lower of y
  ylab("Value") +
  xlab("
       Timing")+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0.25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, 5), limits = c(0, 50), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = .6, colour = "black", linetype=1),         
        axis.text = element_text( angle = 0, color="black", size=18, face=2),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=18, face=2),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=18, face=2, margin=margin(r=20))) +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))

print(ggp)
```

[image]

Comment: if you like it, could you please mark it as an answer, so it will be useful to others when they check